# Passing bundle to activity set as singletask

Tags: java, android, android-activity

So I have a MapActivity that runs an asynchtask that occasionally updates what exactly it's displaying on the map (via a string). I originally pass this string in from the intent when the activity is first created. And then if you click on one of the drawables on the map, it opens a new activity, which can then create a new mapview (same class) with a different string setting. The problem I have is that I only want one instance of the mapview to be running at once. Thus I set android:launchmode="singletask" in the manifest. This works in that it brings the mapactivity to the front, but is there any way to send it a new intent bundle to get a new setting for the string it needs? I tried regetting the extras from the bundle, but it seems to retain the old bundle, not the new intent that was passed to it. I'm not sure I want to do startActivityForResult because the 2nd activity may or may not want to update the original activity.

I hope that made sense. I can post code if necessary, but I think that should explain my situation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When your activity flagged as `singleTask` is already running and a new `Intent` is sent to it, [`onNewIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) will be called to tell you about it.

By default, this new Intent does *not* get stored in any way after that call returns, and the default implementation does nothing.  If you override `onNewIntent`, you can process the extras attached to the new intent directly from there and/or use `setIntent` to attach the new intent to your Activity so that future `getIntent().get*Extra(...)` calls will return the updated data.

Note that there is one special case: if your `singleTask` activity has launched another activity in its task (i.e. an embeddable activity without the NEW_TASK flag), that activity will come to the foreground when your activity receives an intent, but the intent itself will then be silently dropped.  Be careful about that.  See [the Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#lmodes) for more info.