# How can I know the startActivity intent from other application?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an Activity and assume that has been launched. When the other application use startActivity method to start my Activity, my Activity will show and run the onResume Method, but I can't find any way to get the intent which is used in startActivity method by the other application. I want to get the extra data in the intent. How can I do?

**EDIT**

My Activity is singleTask, and I want to get the startActivity intents form other applications. I think it is not associate with filters.

Comment: Check : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [getIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent()) ?

Then you can do:

```
this.getIntent().getExtras();
```

After that if you need new intents just override the [onNewIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) function in your activity.

Comment: My Activity has been launched, so getIntent() method will return the intent from the first launching. However, I want to know the intent from the other application while my Activity is already running.

Comment: onNewIntent(intent) method is the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I simply say an example. When we need to share something. We click share button which shows a list of app by which we can share our things.

So, if you want to make that kind of app which can receive other app data then you need make your activity capable of receiving that data. In order to receive implicit intents, you must include the `CATEGORY_DEFAULT` category in the intent filter in manifest.

Below this link you will get some more information : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html

Comment: You are right, I want to implement a SEND action Activity. I have set up my intent filter. But I encountered this trouble, because my Activity is singleTask.

Comment: I want to carry files from the other applications, and make a list. But I don't know how to get the intents from the other applications while my activity is running.

Comment: I did not faced that kind of problem. But I searched it. please see this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688763/passing-bundle-to-activity-set-as-singletask . it might help.

Comment: Good! I have known how to handle it.